# "Para al que le apetezca" o "Para el que le apetezca"

Tags: gramática

Son ambas oraciones correctas?

1. Estoy cocinando arroz para **el** que le apetezca.
2. Estoy cocinando arroz para **al** que le apetezca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is incorrect. Take into account that "al" is the shortened form of "a el", so in the second one you are really saying

> Estoy cocinando arroz para **a el** que le apetezca.

As you can see using the two prepositions together "para a" has no sense. `Para` is used here to explain who you are cooking for, so it has no sense to add another preposition (which will have its own function) right after it.

Comment: Another possibility would be *para el a(l) que le apetezca*.

Comment: @guifa, ¿querrás decir quizás *para la que le apetezca*? No encuentro sentido a lo que has escrito.

Comment: @Paloma Imagino que para ti una oración como «Estoy cocinando arroz para el hombre al que le apetecería comerlo» tendrá sentido, ¿no?

Comment: @guifa Ah, ya te sigo. Ahora que lo pienso creo que sí sería correcto *para el al que le apetezca* (*al* y no *a*), pero, como suena tan mal y se puede usar otra expresión, no sé si está admitida.

Comment: @guifa Lo mismo con *para el a quien le apetezca*.